# How to fit image to screen with @media?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a front page with an image that looks great in mobile view but as soon as it comes to desktop, it takes it upon itself to blow itself up 2 or 3 times the original size so that only a portion of the image is visible.

What's causing this and how to rectify please?

I mean even in mobile, although it looks fine there, it's blowing itself up, without instructions from me I might add and for seemingly no reason.

Html:

```
<div id="content" class="main-container">
<section class="content-area  pt0 ">
<div id="main" class="" role="main">
<div id="shapely_home_parallax-3" class="widget 
shapely_home_parallax">     <section class="cover fullscreen 
image-bg">
<div class="parallax-window fullscreen" data-parallax="scroll" data- 
image-src="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-- 
content/uploads/2019/06/IMG_20190622_134847-1.jpg" data-ios- 
fix="true" data-over-scroll-fix="true" data-android-fix="true">
<div class="align-transform">
<div class="row">
<div class="top-parallax-section">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text- 
center">                            
<div class="mb32"></div><a class="btn btn-lg btn-white" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-place- 
ad/">Post</a><a class="btn btn-lg btn-filled" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/">Search</a>                                
</div>
```

Page: https://adsler.co.uk

Tried:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {.image-bg {background-size: cover; position: relative;}}
```

Nothing.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Since the image is in portrait mode but the container where you show it is wider than higher it cuts off bottom and top parts. The width seems to be 100% regardless. Meaning if you want to show the full image you would have empty whitespace on the sides.

Comment: There's some truth to that but I still recon I can eak out an inch or so before it hits the margins. How to do this please?

Comment: I assume you are using some plugin there, since the element is changing it's own css with window resize, probably should look into the plugin settings. However if I look at the original of the image and what is displayed on the website (atleast for me) it really is at 100% already. Just look at the shirt on right side and balloon on left side, they are on the edge in original and are also not cut off on your website.

Comment: OK. Do you have a solution even if it means whitespace either side/top/bottom? Like background-size: 75% or something?

Comment: As in 75% of original width / height etc..

Comment: Even moving the image down the page a bit would be also helpful if you know how? Everything I've tried in this regard `like margin/padding`simply moves the header whilst the image stays put. Thanks.

Comment: There is also definitely an issue with auto resizing as, even in mobile, it's bigger than original....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the image position/size add the following css rule:

```
img.parallax-slider {
    width: 75% !important;
    height: auto !important; /* maintain aspect ratio */
    top: 0 !important; /* position from page top, use negative value to move image up */
    left: 50% !important; /* align left side of image with the center of page */
    transform: translateX(-50%) !important; /* move image left by half it's width */
}
```

Note that you need to use `!important` to override the element's style assigned by the plugin. `left` and `transform` are used to center the image if you choose to display white-space on sides.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. But as soon as I move the `top: 0` to `top: minus` it moves the image down a fixed amount regardless of whether this number is `-1` or `-10`

Comment: Did you add a unit? `px, em, %` etc, any will work.

Comment: Used px. Worked. Thanks.